# React Native (Expo) Asyncstorage not working on Google Play version of the app

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

Title pretty much explains it. I have a Asyncstorage system that stores test results. It works fine on emulator and from Expo app, yet it doesnt work when app is downloaded from Google Play store. I don't get any errors on the playstore version.
[Picture of the results tab on Expo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoXXy.png)
[Picture of the results tab on Google Play version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vsE.png)

Comment: Can you edit the post and add some additional details. How does it not work? Does it throw an error/crash or just nothing happens? Also knowing the Expo SDK version and seeing some code would help. The only suggestions I can give based on the description is to double check that the import is `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` which is the version you want to use with Expo.

Comment: Edited a post a bit, hope it's more clearer now. Code is ok, i think it has something to do with Google Play

Comment: Hmm, still not much information to go off from. It sounds like something is not configured properly or there's a bug in the async-storage library. Check the GitHub issues over there for something similar. I see that you're new to SO so if you're still having trouble, write message me at https://t.me/rrebase & I'll give you some tips on how to debug this.